# How to compile Poco with Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7)?

Tags: qt, compilation, poco

I want to use Poco ([pocoproject.org](http://pocoproject.org)) library in my QT C++ app. and I know how to compile poco in a UNIX or cygwin environment. BUT what i want is to complie poco directly in QT under windows. 
 so , what should I do ? 
   Thanks a lot.

Comment: what have you tried and did not work? You want the library to be compiled when you are compiling your Qt app??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Poco libraries have something special, so basically you will have to compile Poco with the same compiler you use Qt with (MinGW or VC++), you can't "compile it in Qt" (because Qt is a framework not an compiler) and after you built it you add it to the qmake projects using [INCLUDEPATH and LIBS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries)